# CPR but plot them at 4 am instead of market open

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

This script works fantastic as it plots the CPR correctly; however, it draws the CPR only after the market opens. However, the data needed to calculate the pivots is available at market close the previous day.

What do I have to modify in the following script so that the trading view can calculate and plot the CPR at 4 am daily?

```
study(title="Central Pivot Range", shorttitle="CPR", overlay=true) 
sd = input(true, title="Show Daily Pivots?")

//Pivot Range Calculations - Mark Fisher
pivot = (high + low + close ) / 3.0 
bc = (high + low ) / 2.0 
tc = (pivot - bc) + pivot

//Daily Pivot Range 
dtime_pivot = security(tickerid, 'D', pivot[1]) 
dtime_bc = security(tickerid, 'D', bc[1]) 
dtime_tc = security(tickerid, 'D', tc[1]) 

offs_daily = 0 
plot(sd and dtime_pivot ? dtime_pivot : na, title="Daily Pivot",style=circles, color=fuchsia,linewidth=3) 
plot(sd and dtime_bc ? dtime_bc : na, title="Daily BC",style=circles, color=blue,linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_tc ? dtime_tc : na, title="Daily TC",style=circles, color=blue,linewidth=3)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely what you're looking for, but this will start drawing next day's pivots on the last bar of the session. You can use this as a starting point to code your specific needs.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Central Pivot Range", shorttitle="CPR", max_lines_count=500, overlay=true) 

i_timeframe = input.timeframe('D', 'timeframe')
i_type      = input.string("DeMark", "Type", options=["Traditional", "Fibonacci", "Woodie", "Classic", "DeMark", "Camarilla"])

dayChange = session.islastbar_regular
pivotPointsArray = ta.pivot_point_levels(i_type, dayChange)

if dayChange or timeframe.change(i_timeframe)
    for pivotLevel in pivotPointsArray
        line.new(time, pivotLevel, time + timeframe.in_seconds(i_timeframe) * 1000, pivotLevel, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

[image]